# Does Eigen assume aliasing?

Tags: c++, eigen

[Matrix multiplication is the only operation in Eigen that assumes aliasing by default](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicAliasing.html).

```
MatrixXf mat1(2,2); 
mat1 << 1, 2,  4, 7;
MatrixXf mat2 = mat1;
auto result = mat1 * mat2;
```

Eigen evaluates the product `mat1 * mat2` in a temporary matrix which is then used to initialize `result` after the computation. As `result` does not appear in the right hand side, we do not need aliasing:

```
MatrixXf result;
result.noalias() = mat1 * mat2;
```

Now, the product `mat1 * mat2` is directly evaluated into `result`.

So far, so good. But what happens in this case?

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto multiplication(const T1& A, const T2& B) // I'm using C++17, decltype not needed
{
    return A*B;
}

int main()
{
    auto result = multiplication(mat1, mat2); // say mat1 and mat2 are the same as above
    // or even this
    mat1 = multiplication(mat1, mat2);
    return 0;
}
```

I would say no aliasing occurs as the `multiplication(m1,m2)` is an `rvalue` and constructed directly in `result` thanks to RVO. And I would say the same for the line `mat1 = multiplication(mat1, mat2).` We could then say that there is a way to multiply `mat1` with another matrix and store the result in the same matrix `mat1` without using a temporary matrix (so, avoiding aliasing).

**Question**:

Does Eigen assume aliasing here or is my assumption correct?

Comment: You seem to treat something like `auto result = mat1 * mat2;` as an assignment.

Comment: `auto result = mat1 * mat2;` is (in C++17) an initialization, not an assignment. It does not use `operator=`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Ok, I'll edit that sentence (I copy pasted it from Eigen docs).

Comment: @MaxLanghof Could you please point me to the sentence that is wrongly expressed? I understand assignment vs initialization, yet fail to see which sentence I expressed bad.

Comment: Yes that was a mistake and I already deleted the comment. You were correctly referring to the code above (and not below) the sentence in question, my bad.

Comment: Can you multiply two square matrices and put the result in the first one without using any additional storage? Try doing this with exactly two postit notes, prlencil and eraser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should also read the [Common Pitfall](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html) regarding using the `auto` keyword.

If you write

```
MatrixXf mat1, mat2;
auto result = mat1 * mat2;
```

or

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto multiplication(const T1& A, const T2& B) { return A*B; }
```

then the type of `auto` actually is just something like `Product<MatrixXf, MatrixXf>` or `Product<T1,T2>`, i.e., no computation at all happens at that point.

Therefore

```
MatrixXf mat1 = MatrixXf::Random(2,2), mat2 = MatrixXf::Random(2,2);

auto result = multiplication(mat1, mat2); // no computation happens here

// this is safe (Eigen assumes aliasing can happen):
mat1 = result; // equivalent to directly assign mat1 = mat1 * mat2;
// Pitfall: "result" now refers to a modified `mat1` object!

// this will give undefined results (you may need bigger matrices to actually see this):
mat1.noalias() = mat1*mat2; // tell Eigen this does not alias, but actually it does.
```

---

Addendum: In the comments the difference between assignment and initialization has been pointed out. In fact, during initialization Eigen assumes no aliasing happens, e.g., the following directly assigns to result (without temporaries):

```
MatrixXf result = mat1 * mat2; // initialization, not assignment!
```

---

Addendum 2: If you wrote (assuming the return type of `foo` is `Object`):

```
Object A;
A = foo(A);
```

there must be some kind of implicit assignment happening (with C++11 likely a move-assignment, if `Object` allows that). This is different to

```
Object A;
Object B = foo(A); // RVO possible (depending on foo).
```

Comment: I did not think about the auto pitfall. I was able to confirm the type of result (Product<T1,T2>). If I rewrote my template like template <typename T> T multiplication(const T& A, const T& B) { return A*B; }, then auto result = multiplication(A,B);, as I understand from your answer, result would be initialized and no aliasing would occur. Correct?

Comment: Correct and it should be optimized by RVO -- **as long as it still compiles** (it won't compile, e.g., for `Matrix4f A`, `Vector4f B`, in contrast to your `template<T1, T2>` solution).

Comment: Ok, but as you said, auto deduces a type Product<T1,T2>. Maybe, I could rewrite the template as: template<typename T1, typename T2> multiplication(const T1& A, const T2& B) -> decltype((A*B).eval()). If Matrix4f A and Vector4f B, then auto result = multiplication(A,B) would then work: the type of result would be Vector4f and the initialization of result would not imply temporaries.

Comment: Yes, `auto result = multiplication(A,B);` would not have temporaries, but `B = multiplication(A,B);` would have. And `MatrixXf result; result = multiplication(A,B);` would also create a temporary (but likely gets move-assigned). Overall, I do not see what you want to achieve in contrast to simply writing `result = A*B;`

Comment: Nothing really. The function multiplication was just an attempt to provide a minimal example. The function I use in my code is not a simple product. I could (and should) have left the multiplication part out.